# How to show Content Titles only in Entity Reference drop down list, but restrict general access to the Content Type?

Tags: 7, entities, users

Drupal 7.25

I have a list of "Locations" (content type) and need people to select an item from this list when they register on the site.

However, I do not want anonymous or authenticated users to view the detailed contents of these locations.

When I restrict the permissions on the content type, this removes all the values from the entity reference list for anonymous users when they try and register.

So is there an easy way to show ONLY the content Title field in the list, without people being able to then see all the other fields for the content type?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the only way I found to do this was install the field_permisssions module and restrict access to all the custom fields for specific roles.

Not ideal, but achieves the objectives. There are a lot of fields and it took quite a while. Also need to remember to restrict fields when creating new ones.